# Preventing browser caching with meta-tags after the body

Tags: html

So, I was reading this: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881

In an effort to solve browser caching issues.  One of the solutions the author suggests is putting the meta tags in a second head tag after the body.  This is bad markup, but I believe it is also the case that meta tags must be in the head.

Here's an example of what the author suggests:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Stuff </p>
    </body>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
    </head>
</html>
```

The idea is that putting the meta tags in the head prevents caching before the buffer is filled, so we're putting them inside another head after the body, since by then the buffer will have been filled. Is the author's solution viable, or do I need to look elsewhere for browser caching prevention?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: Trying to specify cache control information using meta tags is a bad idea. Use HTTP headers. (As for the author's suggestions … well I once bought one of his books for 50p and then used it to make other web developers recoil in horror).

Comment: @Quentin look like u are affiliate of author  :)

Comment: @Quentin, yeah, if your solution violates the principles of the markup language you're using, that's a pretty bad sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now a days,its good practice to tell browser through headers to avoid caching the page. You can do it by sending the following headers:

```
unset Cache-Control
 append Cache-Control "no-cache"
 append Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate"
```

You can send them via .htaccess in case of Apache or through ur back end scripting language for example through header(); in php. You will need to send the headers before any data is outputted

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for.  Thanks.  I'll be using your php header(); solution